# How can my button close the window and refresh the parent after updating formview?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, entity-framework, gridview, formview

I have a "Save" button on a FormView with the CommandName="Update" set. This button updates an EntityDataSource that is bound to the FormView.

After the EDS is updated, I want to close this (child, popup) window and refresh my parent window (so it will reflect the changes just made to the data).

For reference, I have a similar "Cancel" button on this page that simply calls a Javascript function "OnClientClick":

```
function done() {
   if (window.opener.closed) {
      self.close();
   } else {
      window.opener.focus();
      window.opener.location.href = opener.location;
      self.close();
   }
}
```

Now, how can I let the FormView and EDS do its thing (process the Update command) and then call this javascript function (or code to accomplish the equivalent)???

After doing some more digging, I solved it. The problem had to do with the FormView being inside an Update Panel. I had to use the following:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.UpdatePanel1, typeof(string), "done", "done();", true);
```

Comment: Was it a modal dialog? I would worry about being cross-browser comptabible.

Comment: No, just an aspx page. It only has to work with IE and this is code runing on a JSP web seerver that I am porting to.Net. The script has worked for our users with no problems for years. I just need to figure out how to call it (or accomplish the same thing) from code behind. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as your update is finished, it should return a page that you can just register your function with.  In your `Update` command handler (assuming this is happening server side), just add the following:

```
Page.RegisterStartupScript("AfterUpdate", "done();");
```

It will cause the `done()` javascript function to run as soon as the windows refreshes from the postback caused by the update command.  If you `done` function isn't already in the page, make sure you add it's definition before you call it to the `RegisterStartupScript` call.

Comment: I am using an EntityDataSource bound to a FormView and I dont have a specific command handler. But, I do have an "OnUpdated" handler. I have tried adding it to this handler and I have tried adding a handler for the click event on the save button and putting it in there. 

The "done" function is in the master page. I have also tried putting the actual javascript code in the RegisterStartupScript instead of calling "done".

Maybe just a differnece in .Net Versions, but the code I am using is:

ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "Javascript", "javascript: done(); ", true);

Comment: After doing some more digging, I solved it. The problem had to do with the FormView being inside an Update Panel. I had to use the following:

ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.UpdatePanel1, typeof(string), "done", "done();", true);

Comment: @Shayne if this answer helped you don't forget to set the accepted answer so others don't try to answer it as well.  You also get 2 rep points for setting the accepted answer :)